# I would like to import two columns into Wordpress

Tags: bulk-import, phpmyadmin, csv

Very easy- I would like to import two columns, `list-id` and `slider` in a CSV into my Wordpress database. `list-id` must match with Wordpress post. That's it

I have used many Wordpress plugins, but they are slow. TurboCSV seems the best. How can this be done in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Adding content directly in the database is generally not the best idea. Can you please explain in more detail what your data is, maybe with sample data?

Comment: I am trying to add a custom field called `slider` which is a list of urls. `www.domain.com/1.jpg|www.domain.com/2.jpg

Comment: And how do they match up to the post ID?

Comment: They don't which is the current problem. I have 150K posts to match with images in sepearte csv's.

Comment: Well how do they match in your CSV files? Again - please add some samples of this CSV data.

Comment: Ok with `list-id' e.g of header and row `list-id|slider
4110|"http://images.travelnow.com/hotelimages/s/010000/010489A.jpg|http://images.travelnow.com/hotelimages/s/010000/010489B.jpg|http://images.travelnow.com/hotelimages/s/010000/010489C.jpg` `list-id` is also in the post custom field.